# Comparing large list of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a form that contains a list of objects that are all updated at once.  In the controller, a nested loop compares each model to the other models so it can determine which objects have been updated and which are new.

```
foreach(var x in formObject)
{
    foreach(var y in dbObject)
    {
        if(x.id == y.id)
        {
             //compare each property and notify user of change if different
        }
    }
}
```

This takes a huge amount of time considering the large number of objects and how slow the servers are.

Is there a better practice for doing this?  Some way of determining which objects have been updated before looping through all?  Or a more efficient loop?

Comment: Is keeping track of changes as they happen not an option?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Since this is ASP.NET, I'm assuming the changes are all happening on the client side in a single large form and submitted in bulk to the server.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Completely missed that! Need coffee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put all the dbObjects in a dictionary, using the ids as the key. Then you can just look up each object in the dictionary, instead of having to iterate over all objects:

```
var dbObjects = new Dictionary<int, ObjectModel>();
foreach(var y in dbObject)
{
    dbObjects.Add(y.id, y);
}

foreach(var x in formObject)
{
    ObjectModel y;
    if(dbObjects.TryGetValue(x.id, out y))
    {
        //compare each property and notify user of change if different
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a join in Linq:

```
var differences = 
    from x in formObject
    join y in dbObject on x.id equals y.id
    where ( /* compare each property */ )
    select new { /* what do you want to tell the user */ };
```

Of course, without more information about what's in the loop, that's just about all the code I could provide.

In fluent syntax that would be:

```
var differences =
    formObject.Join(dbObject, x => x.id, y => y.id, (x, y) => new { x, y })
              .Where(p => /* compare properties of p.x and p.y */)
              .Select(p => new { /* what do you want to tell the user */ });
```